# Acessar variáveis de ambiente com espaço no path

Tags: git, path, variáveis-de-ambiente

Criei uma variável de ambiente que armazena um `path` com espaço:

```
/c/Users/Bruno Xavier
```

Apesar de estar no windows, a minha intenção é usa-lá pelo `git bash` para facilitar o acesso ao diretório.

Tentei as duas alternativas mais óbvias:

- Encapsular o path com aspas: `"/c/Users/Bruno Xavier"`
- Pular o espaço em branco: `/c/Users/Bruno\ Xavier`

Nenhuma delas funcionou.
A única solução que consigo é:

`"$my_var" com my_var = /c/Users/Bruno Xavier`

Contudo, gostaria de acessar `cd $my_var` sem precisar no terminal digitar as aspas

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida afinal?

Comment: Quero digitar `$my_var` e não `"$my_var"`

Answer (score -1):

Creio que não seja possível, pela forma como o bash funciona.

Se você tem na variável `$my_var` o diretório `/c/Users/Bruno Xavier`, a execução do seguinte comando sem as aspas:

```
cd $my_var
```

Dá a entender ao shell que você que fazer um `cd /c/Users/Bruno` e `Xavier`:

```
cd /c/Users/Bruno Xavier
```

O que para o `cd` não faz muito sentido. Primeiro porque não existe o diretório `/c/Users/Bruno` e segundo porque não existe um parâmetro `Xavier` para ser interpretado como argumento do comando `cd`.

Por esta razão, é necessário passar as aspas duplas:

```
cd "$my_var"
```

Se tiver algum impedimento em usar as duplas no seu problema, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta explicando qual é este impedimento, para direcionar para uma resposta diferente.

Comment: Essa é uma boa explicação. Mas ainda não entendi o caso `cd $my_var` onde `my_var="/c/Users/Bruno Xavier"` com aspas na variável de ambiente.

Comment: Qual a dúvida? Se fizer apenas `cd my_var` creio que o bash vai entender que quer ir em um diretório chamado `my_var` e não que quer ler o conteúdo da variável `$my_var`. Seria esta a dúvida?

Comment: Faltou '$'. Seria `cd $my_var`

Comment: Independente se a variável foi guardada com aspas duplas ou não, o bash vai traduzir a variável para `/c/Users/Bruno Xavier`. Sem as aspas duplas no momento de fazer o `cd`, o problema descrito vai acontecer.

Comment: Se se eu der scape `/c/Users/Bruno\ Xavier`? `cd` não deveria ser agora capaz de achar o diretório?